# How can I speed up a slow SUM + ORDER BY + LIMIT query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a simple key-value table with two fields, created like so:

```
 CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
    `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `value` double NOT NULL,
    KEY `MYKEY` (`key`)
 );
```

The keys are not unique. The table contains over one million records. I need a query that will sum up all the values for a given key, and return the top 10 keys. Here's my attempt:

```
  SELECT t.key, SUM(t.value) value
  FROM mytable t
  GROUP BY t.key
  ORDER BY value DESC
  LIMIT 0, 10;
```

But this is *very* slow. Thing is, without the GROUP BY and SUM, it's pretty fast, and without the ORDER BY, it's very fast, but for some reason the combination of the two makes it very very slow. Can anyone explain why this is so, and how this can be speeded up?

---

There is no index on value. I tried creating one but it didn't help.

---

EXPLAIN EXTENDED produces the following in Workbench:

```
 id select_type table type  possible_keys key   key_len ref  rows    filtered Extra 
 1  SIMPLE      t     index NULL          MYKEY 257     NULL 1340532 100.00   "Using temporary; Using filesort"
```

---

There are about 400K unique keys in the table.

---

The query takes over 3 minutes to run. I don't know how long because I stopped it after 3 minutes. **However**, if I remove the index on key, it runs in 30 seconds! Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Do you have an index on value?

Comment: Can you give us the output of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` for that query?

Comment: The query will be generating an intermediate table and then sorting it. I suspect the slow bit is the sorting, though neither will be quick. How many unique keys do you have? You won't be able to effectively index value as you are calculating it as part of the query.

Comment: @MarloGuthrie Click "edit" below your question to update it with more information. Code in comments is barely readable.

Comment: Could you try adding adding an extra table link the key with an int field, then on this table store the int. My idea is that if each of the occurances of key is close to the max (ie, 255 chars) then that is at least 100mb just for that index which might be causing memory related slowness.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really speed this up, as far as I can see, is to create a seperate table with unique keys in and maintain the total values. Then you will be able to index values to retrieve the top ten quickly, also the calculation will already be done. As long as the table is not updated in too many places, this shouldn't be a major problem.

The major problem with this type of query is that the `group by` requires indexing in one order and the `order by` requires sorting into a different order.

Comment: Jaydeep ,so we need to update record in new table each time record changes in main table.how can we achieve this  using trigger or something esle?